# How to fill in the status for Facebook sharing button

Tags: html, facebook, meta

Below is the code am using now to share my status on Facebook. The problem is that the description is not autofill in the facebook status field.

When user clicks on this link, its take them to share status page

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.4fj.com.fj/get-involved/take-the-pledge/" class="share_button share_fb"></a>
```

Yes, I do have all the necessary facebook meta tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo the_title(); ?>" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="I made the #4FJ pledge to not eat, buy or sell kawakawa and donu during the june-sept spawning season. Check out my pledge and others at http://www.4fj.com.fj/get-involved/our-pledgers. Then join the movement." />  
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/logo.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo curPageURL(); ?>" />
```

I' am I doing something or is their something missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.4fj.com.fj/get-involved/take-the-pledge
```

its works for me. you can check link.